# Doble bucle for dentro de una clase en Javascript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, class

Alguien sabe como funciona los bucles `for` dentro de una clase en `javascript`?.

Tengo el método `ordenarArrayDeNumeros` dentro de la clase; se supone que debería ordenar los números.

Funciona bien si no esta dentro una clase, pero cuando esta dentro de una, se repite el bucle mas veces de lo que debería.

```
class OrdenarNumeros{
        constructor(_array){
            this.coleccionNumeros = _array
            this.mayor = this.coleccionNumeros[0]
            this.menor = this.coleccionNumeros[0]
            this.nombre = 'Alejandro'
            this.arrayDeNumerosOrdenados = []

        }
        encontrarMenor(){

            for(var i=0; i < this.coleccionNumeros.length; i++){

                if(this.menor > this.coleccionNumeros[i]){
                    this.menor = this.coleccionNumeros[i]                         
                }
            }                         
        }
        encontrarMayor(){
            for(let elemento in this.coleccionNumeros){
                if(this.mayor < this.coleccionNumeros[elemento]){
                    this.mayor = this.coleccionNumeros[elemento]
                }
            }

        }
        ordenarArrayDeNumeros(){
            this.tachador = 'x'
            this.extraerIndice 

            for( let x in this.coleccionNumeros){

                this.menor = this.mayor

                for(let y in this.coleccionNumeros){
                    if(this.coleccionNumeros[y] != 'x'){
                        if(this.menor > this.coleccionNumeros[x]){
                            this.menor = this.coleccionNumeros[x]
                            this.extraerIndice = x
                        }
                    }        
                }

                this.arrayDeNumerosOrdenados.push(this.menor)
                this.coleccionNumeros[this.extraerIndice] = this.tachador   
            }
            console.log(this.arrayDeNumerosOrdenados)
        }
    }
    const ordenarNumeros = new OrdenarNumeros([90,70,1000,100,150,2,33])

    ordenarNumeros.ordenarArrayDeNumeros()//[[90, 70, 90, 90, 90, 2, 33]]
```

Comment: podrias explicar un poco de que es lo que realmente deseas hacer? y cual deberia ser el resultado esperado??

Comment: El resultado esperado deberia ser los numeros ordenados de el array [90,70,1000,100,150,2,33], pero no funciona debido a que dentro de la clase en el metodo "ordenarArrayDeNumeros()" los bucles for se comportan de manera extraña y me dan como resultado [90, 70, 90, 90, 90, 2, 33]

Comment: He probado el código tal cual pero modificando una sola cosa: en vez de dejarlo dentro de una clase lo he ejecutado por medio de una función, pero usando exactamente las mismas variables que tu, pero el resultado es el mismo resultado erroneo que te pasa con la clase, quizá deberias revisar mejor el código ya que el código de por si me plantea muchas dudas logicas debido a que hay cosas que no les encuentro tanto sentido... de todas el resultado para mi fue el mismo al probar tu código tanto fuera como dentro de una clase, que el código este dentro del metodo de una clase no debe afectar.

Comment: Mi problema fue una mejor de comprensión sobre como funcionan las propiedades y los métodos en una clase. Creí que un método modifica directamente una propiedad en la clase y no es así. Además hice una pequeñísima  mala lógica en el bucle anidado. Al final logre resolverlo, pero no se como mostrarte el código la caja de comentarios no me permite pegar todo el código